# Lock camera position in VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm playing around with VR a bit, so far I can move a character around and such. However the position of the camera is changing. I want my camera to be in a fixed position and only be able to change up/down position and the normal rotation with the HMD.

```
void Start ()
{
    startPos = transform.localPosition;
    parentObj = transform.root;
}

void Update()
{
    ResetVR();
}

void ResetVR()
{
    if (parentObj != null)
    {
        startPos -= InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(VRNode.CenterEye);       
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(parentObj.localRotation);
    }
}
```

With this my character rotates normally but the camera won't stay in a fixed position.

For example, if I rotate 90 degrees, the camera ends up left of the character. I want the camera stay in a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to up/down. This is the-same as rotating around x-axis only. Get the original position. Convert the `Quaternion` to angle then rotate with `transform.localEulerAngles` instead of `transform.localRotation`.Overwrite the other two axis(y,z) with `originalPos` variables before rotating. You may *need* to modify this to get it working properly.

```
Transform parentObj;
Vector3 startPos;
Vector3 originalPos;

void Start()
{
    startPos = transform.localPosition;
    originalPos = transform.localPosition;
    parentObj = transform.root;
}

void Update()
{
    ResetVR();
}

void ResetVR()
{
    if (parentObj != null)
    {
        startPos -= InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(VRNode.CenterEye);

        Quaternion tempRot = Quaternion.Inverse(parentObj.localRotation);
        Vector3 newAngle = tempRot.eulerAngles;
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(newAngle.x, originalPos.y, originalPos.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works 50/50, however the rotation is now 90 degrees more if I turn my head 90 degrees. The code what I had, was fixing this.

Comment: What do you mean by 50/50? What angle does it rotate 90 degrees more?

Comment: The position of the camera is good but the rotation ain't. The values of the component say that it is right though. How ever with the VR glasses it turns 90 degrees more.

Comment: Ok. So which axis? When you say 90 degrees more...you mean on the left, right up or down?

Comment: Aah sorry, left and right. When i look left or right i watch behind me with the camera. So X-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [this rule](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/944029/oculus-rift-how-can-i-restrict-camera-rotation.html).

See [Unity's documentation](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/movement-vr) about this.

Comment: I know that, I changed my question a bit. I only dont want the lean movements with VR.